# Open mapping theorem and second category

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

This seems like a fundamental result but I can not solve it of find an solution:
Let $M:X\rightarrow U$ be a bounded linear map between Banach spaces. Show that if the 
range of M is a set of second category of U; then the range is all of U.

Comment: This is very confusing to me. Your statement is not true and the title does not seem to involve the question at all. For a counterexample consider something like the diagonal operator $e_n \mapsto e_n/n$ on $\ell^1(\mathbb N)$.

Comment: @JacobSchlather, why don't you post this comment as answer?

Comment: Sorry I wrote it wrong, it is corrected now.

Comment: @Norbert, I usually post as a comment when I think someone meant to ask something different and I'm unsure if I'll be able to answer their actual question.

Comment: The title doesn't seem to be at all related to the question.

Comment: I think the [standard proof](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_mapping_theorem_%28functional_analysis%29) of the Open Mapping Theorem, where the hypothesis that "$M$ is onto" is replaced by "$\text{Ran}(M)$ is of second category" can be slightly altered to give your result. In fact, more is true: If $X$ is a Banach space, $Y$ is  a normed space,   $M:X\rightarrow Y$ is continuous, linear, and $M(X)$ is of second category, then: 1) $M$ is onto, 2) $M$ is an open mapping, and 3) $Y$ is complete.  This (ever further generalized) is Theorem 2.11 in Walter Rudin's *Functional Analysis*.

Comment: Should the title say "second category" instead of "second countable"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume that the range is of second category but the range of $M$ is not $U$. As $M(X)$ is not closed (otherwise $M(X)$ would be of first category, as it's a strict subspace), we can apply [this result](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/177530/range-of-bounded-operator-is-of-first-category/177586#177586) to $Y=\overline{M(X)}$.

Comment: That was a long one! Is there no easier way?

Comment: I don't know, but what we have to show is strongly related to what is done in the link.