# Bounded linear operator (between Banach spaces) with second category range has closed range

Tags: functional-analysis

I'm attempting a problem about closed range of a bounded linear operator.

> Assume $X, Y$ are Banach spaces and $A$ is a bounded linear operator. 
>   If $\operatorname{Ran}(A)$ is of the second category,
>   then show that $\operatorname{Ran}(A)$ is closed.

I want to use the Closed Graph Theorem and assume that $Ax_i \to y$ in $Y$,
if we can show that $x_i \to x$ in $X$, then the result follows by continuity of $A$. But I'm having a hard time showing that $\{x_i\}$ is a convergent sequence in $X$, and don't know how to use the fact that $\operatorname{Ran}(A)$ is of the second category.

Any help would be appeciated!

Comment: Why do you want to apply closed graph? $A$ is *bounded* by assumption.

Comment: @Jochen. The Closed Graph is a ``iff" statement. $A$ being continuous implies that if you have  $x_i \to x$ and $Ax_i \to y$ then $Ax = y$. It remains to show that for arbitrary $Ax_i \to y$, my $x_i$ actually converges.

Comment: But that's not true: It may very well be that $Ax_i=0$ for all $i$ but $x_i$ do not converge. Your question is about the open mapping theorem.

Comment: @Jochen. Indeed, it might not be true in general, but I'm curious how the condition that $\text{Ran}(A)$ is of the second category jumps in.

Comment: This is classical form of the open mapping theorem, see, e.g., Rudin's *Functional Analysis*, Theorem 2.11.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hints only.

The second category assumption lets you prove that $A(B_X(1))$ is dense in some ball $B_Y(\epsilon)\cap\mathrm{Ran}(A).$ Use this to show that for $y\in\overline{\mathrm{Ran}(A)},$ you can inductively pick a sequence $x_n$ with $\sum x_n$ converging absolutely and $|A\sum x_n-y|\to 0.$

Comment: I'm a bit confused since $y$ should already be in the closure of range of $A$. We need it to be in the range of $A$ which is stronger.

Comment: @octoberbear: I'm saying that for every $y$ in the closure of range of $A,$ you can try to pick a series in $X$ whose sum gets mapped to $y.$ As mentioned in the comments, there's a complete proof in Rudin 2.11

Answer (score 0):

Built on the hints in Dap's answer. Basically mimicking the proof for the Open Mapping Theorem.

**Note:** here the statement "$\text{Ran}(A)$ is of the Second Category" must be understood as "$\text{Ran}(A)$, equipped with the subspace topology, is a Second Category space". It should *not* be understood as being a Second Category subset of $Y$.

*Proof.* Firstly, the closure of the range $\overline{\text{Ran}(A)}$, with its subspace topology, is a Banach space. By the Baire Category Theorem, it is of Second Category. Also, the subspace topology of $\text{Ran}(A)$, inherited from $Y$, coincides with that inherited from the closure $\overline{\text{Ran}(A)}$. If $\text{Ran}(A)$ is a Second Category space, it is then a Second Category subset in Banach space $\overline{\text{Ran}(A)}$. Hence, since
$$\text{Ran}(A)=\cup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}A(nB_X(1))=\cup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}nA(B_X(1)),$$
there exists $n_0\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\text{Int} \overline{n_0 A(B_X(1))}\neq \emptyset$ in terms of the subspace topology of $\overline{\text{Ran}(A)}$. Then there exists some $r_0>0$ and $y_0\in Y$ such that
$B_Y(y_0, r_0)\cap\overline{\text{Ran}(A)} \subset \overline{n_0 A(B_X(1))}.$
It can therefore be shown that, for every $L>0$,
$B_Y(\frac{r_0}{2n_0}L)\cap \overline{\text{Ran}(A)}\subset \overline{A(B_X(L))}.$

So for every $y\in \overline{\text{Ran}(A)}\setminus\{0\}$, we have $y\in \overline{B_Y(\|y\|_Y)}\cap \overline{\text{Ran}(A)}\subset \overline{A(B_X(\frac{2n_0}{r_0}\|y\|_Y))}$. That is, there exists $x\in B_X(\frac{2n_0}{r_0}\|y\|_Y)$ such that $\|y-Ax\|_Y<\frac{\|y\|_Y}{2}$. But this means
$$y-Ax\in B_Y(\frac{\|y\|_Y}{2})\cap \overline{\text{Ran}(A)}\subset \overline{A(B_X(\frac{2n_0}{r_0}\frac{\|y\|_Y}{2}))}.$$
Hence, we can inductively choose a sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ in $X$ satisfying $\|x_n\|_X< \frac{2n_0}{r_0}\frac{\|y\|_Y}{2^{n-1}}$ and
$$\|y-A(x_1+\cdots +x_n)\|_Y<\frac{\|y\|_Y}{2^{n-1}}.$$
Hence, by the completeness of $X$, $\sum_n x_n$ converges absolutely to some $\xi\in X$. By continuity of $A$, taking the limit gives
$0_Y=\lim_{n\to\infty}(y-A(x_1+\cdots +x_n))=y-A\xi,$
and so $y=A\xi\in \text{Ran}(A)$.

Hence $\text{Ran}(A)=\overline{\text{Ran}(A)}$ is closed. $\square$

Comment: Using a similar approach, one can prove: if $\text{Ran}(A)$ is *not* closed, it is of First Category. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/177586/416552)