# Nowhere dense subsets of a dense subspace are nowhere dense in the whole space and vice versa

Tags: general-topology, baire-category, the-baire-space, dense-subspaces

It seems, with the following lemma, the proposition at the bottom easily follows.

> If $Y\subset X$ dense. Then, for every nonempty $A\subset Y$, $\text{Int}_Y \left(\text{cl}_Y A\right)=Y\cap \text{Int}_X \left(\text{cl}_X A\right)$.

*Proof.* Since $Y$ is dense in $X$, we have $$\text{cl}_X \left(\text{cl}_Y A\right)=\text{cl}_X A; \quad \text{cl}_Y A=Y\cap \text{cl}_XA;\quad Y-\text{cl}_Y A=Y\cap \left(X-\text{cl}_XA\right).$$

If $\text{cl}_Y A=Y$, using the first equality, the conclusion can be easily verified.
Suppose $\text{cl}_Y A\subsetneq Y$. Then, the third equality implies $Y-\text{cl}_YA$ is dense in $\text{cl}_X\left(X-\text{cl}_XA\right)$. Combining this with the second equality, then
$\text{cl}_Y \left(Y-\text{cl}_YA\right)=Y\cap \text{cl}_X\left(Y-\text{cl}_YA\right)=Y\cap \text{cl}_X\left(X-\text{cl}_XA\right),$
and so
\begin{align*}
\partial_Y \left(\text{cl}_YA\right)&=\text{cl}_YA\cap \text{cl}_Y \left(Y-\text{cl}_YA\right)\\
&=\text{cl}_YA\cap Y\cap\text{cl}_X  \left(X-\text{cl}_XA\right)\\
&=Y\cap \text{cl}_XA\cap\text{cl}_X  \left(X-\text{cl}_XA\right)\\
&=Y\cap\partial_X \left(  \text{cl}_XA\right).
\end{align*}
Therefore,
$$\begin{align*}
\text{Int}_Y\left(\text{cl}_Y A\right)
&=\text{cl}_Y A- \partial_Y \left(\text{cl}_YA\right)\\
&=Y\cap \text{cl}_XA- Y\cap\partial_X \left(  \text{cl}_XA\right)\\
&=Y\cap \left(\text{cl}_XA-\partial_X \left(\text{cl}_XA\right)\right)\\
&=Y\cap\text{Int}_X \left(\text{cl}_X A\right).
\end{align*}$$
$\square$

> *Proposition.* If $Y\subset X$ dense. A subset $A\subset Y\subset X$ is nowhere dense in $X$ *iff* it is nowhere dense in $Y$, where $Y$ is given its subspace topology.

*Proof.* If $A$ is nowhere dense in $Y$, by the lemma, $Y\cap \text{Int}_X \left(\text{cl}_X A\right)=\text{Int}_Y \left(\text{cl}_Y A\right)=\emptyset$. But since $Y$ is dense in $X$, $Y\cap \text{Int}_X \left(\text{cl}_X A\right)=\emptyset$ iff $\text{Int}_X \left(\text{cl}_X A\right)=\emptyset$. Hence $A$ is also nowhere dense in $X$. The other direction is even easier, given the lemma. $\square$

Are there any mistakes? Thanks in advance. (Motivated when answering [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2700660/416552) question.)

**Update:**

After searching through the internet for a few days, I found the following proposition in a book called *[Baire Spaces](https://eudml.org/doc/268479)*, by Haworth and McCoy (1977). But it only says "a similar proof" can be given to when $Y$ is dense in $X$, without actually providing it. [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All correct, as far as I can see.

I find the following easier to understand, but that's just personal opinion.

For any $Y$, dense or not, $(cl_X A) \cap Y = cl_Y A$. Hence $int_X(cl_X A) \cap Y \subseteq cl_Y A$ and so $int_X (cl_X A) \cap Y \subseteq int_Y(cl_Y A)$.

The other direction does use denseness. Let $U$ be any open set of $X$ such that $U \cap Y = int_Y(cl_Y A)$. As $cl_Y A \subseteq cl_X A$ we have
$(X \setminus cl_X A) \cap (U \cap Y) = \emptyset$. By denseness $(X \setminus cl_X A) \cap U = \emptyset$, and so $U \subseteq cl_X A$ and $U \subseteq int_X(cl_X A)$. Therefore $int_Y(cl_Y A) \subseteq int_X(cl_X A) \cap Y$.

Comment: Thanks! This does seem to work, and definitely easier to follow. In my question, I went by looking at the boundaries because that way I don't have to worry about empty sets all the time, unlike with interior. So it became messy...

Answer (score 1):

[This is posted as Community Wiki, because it is an alternative
proof, not an assessment of the OP's proof.]

A subset $A$ of a topological space $X$ is nowhere dense in $X$ if
and only if for every nonempty open subset $U$ of $X$ there exists a
nonempty open subset $V$ of $X$ that is contained in $U$ and
disjoint from $A.$

Let $Y$ be a subset of a space $X,$ with the subspace topology, and
let $A$ be a subset of $Y.$ By the criterion just given, $A$ is
nowhere dense in $Y$ if and only if for every open subset $U$ of $X$
such that $U \cap Y \ne \emptyset$ there exists an open subset $V$
of $X$ such that $V \cap Y \ne \emptyset$ and
$V \cap Y \subseteq U \cap Y$ and $(V \cap Y) \cap A = \emptyset.$
Because $A \subseteq Y,$ the last of these three conditions
reduces to $V \cap A = \emptyset.$

Suppose first that $A$ is nowhere dense in $Y$ (making no hypothesis
on $Y$).

Let $U$ be any nonempty open subset of $X.$ If $U$ is disjoint from
$Y,$ then $U$ is also disjoint from $A.$ On the other hand, if $U$
is not disjoint from $Y,$ then by the criterion of the second
paragraph, there exists an open subset $W$ of $X$ such that
$W \cap Y \ne \emptyset$ and $W \cap Y \subseteq U \cap Y$ and
$W \cap A = \emptyset.$ Let $V = U \cap W.$ Then $V$ is an open
subset of $X$ that is contained in $U$ and disjoint from $A,$ and we
have
$$
\emptyset \ne W \cap Y = (W \cap Y) \cap (U \cap Y) =
(W \cap U) \cap Y = V \cap Y,
$$
so $V$ is nonempty.  Thus in all cases, regardless of whether $U$ is
disjoint from $Y,$ there exists a nonempty open subset $V$ of $X$
that is contained in $U$ (equal to $U$ in the first case) and
disjoint from $A.$ Therefore $A$ is nowhere dense in $X.$

For the converse implication, we need the hypothesis that $Y$ is
dense in $X.$ That is, every nonempty open subset of $X$ has a
nonempty intersection with $Y.$

Suppose that $A$ is nowhere dense in $X.$ In the subspace topology
on $Y,$ every nonempty open subset is of the form $U \cap Y,$ where
$U$ is an open subset of $X,$ necessarily nonempty.  Because $U$ is
nonempty, and $A$ is nowhere dense in $X,$ there exists a nonempty
open subset $V$ of $X$ that is contained in $U$ and disjoint from
$A.$ Now $V \cap Y$ is a nonempty open subset of $Y$ that is
contained in $U \cap Y$ and disjoint from $A.$ Therefore $A$ is
nowhere dense in $Y.$