# The image of bounded linear operator is the whole space or first Baire category

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces, baire-category

Let $V$ be a complete normed space and $W$ is normed space. Let $A \subset V$ be closed subspace. If $ T:V \rightarrow W$ is bounded linear operator, then we need to prove that $T(A)$ is either first Baire Category or $T(A)=W$.

My attempt:

If $T$ is surjective then we are done. So, suppose that $T$ is not surjective, then I know we need to show that $T(A)$ is nowhere dense by showing it is contained in a closed set with empty interior but not sure how to prove this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Range of bounded operator is of first category](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/177530/range-of-bounded-operator-is-of-first-category)

Comment: @leslietownes, yes it answers. Thank you!